# how can i combine multiple columns from different sheets

Tags: excel

I have a large database where one column in each sheet is the same.  the number of rows vary, since there are several codes used more than once.  example:

Sheet 1: column 1 (client ID) --> column 2 (client name)

Sheet 2: column 1 (client ID)--> column 2 (loan ID)

sheet 3: column 1 (loan ID) ---> column 2 (loan info)

So I was hoping to get one row with client name (sheet 1) and loan info (sheet 3) plus all the pertaining information in sheet 3

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Excel, vLookup or Index + Match would probably do the trick.  Alternatively, you could use Access to query the results your looking for, however that would take a bit more time to setup.

In the sheet you want the data to display you would use the Vlookup for the specified person in Sheets 1 and then again on Sheet 2.
'Output
Name    State   Loan ID Date of service
Bob AK  112233  1/1/2001
'Formulas
    VLOOKUP($A3,**Sheet1**!$A:$C, ***2***, FALSE)   VLOOKUP($A3,**Sheet1!**$A:$C, ***3***, FALSE)   VLOOKUP(A3, **Sheet2!**$A2:$C5, ***3***, FALSE)